# MVC4 - Javascript Not Accessible After NuGet Deploy - ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, minify

I've just performed the first deployment of my MVC application and I've run into a few problems with the Javascript.

In order to hook things up at run time I do this:

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
@if (IsSectionDefined("MyPage"))
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            @RenderSection("MyPage", required: false)
        });
    </script>
}
```

**MyPage.cshtml**

Then in my Razor views I do this:

```
@section MyPage
{
    myPage.SomeFunction();
}
```

**myPage.js**

```
(function (myPage, $) {

    myPage.SomeFunction = function () {
    ...
    };

}(window.myPage= window.myPage|| {}, jQuery));
```

This is all working great in Debug within VS but as soon as I deploy it (Continuous Deployment with Otopus Deploy in NuGet packages) I start to see errors like:

```
ReferenceError: myPage is not defined.
```

If I view the source and follow the bundle link the code is there ...

But the file is headed with a Minification error like:

```
/* Minification failed. Returning unminified contents.
(683,1-2): run-time warning JS1002: Syntax error: }
(683,51-52): run-time warning JS1002: Syntax error: }
 */
// Contains all the javascript required by the myPage page
```

I'm currently working through the JSLint errors in Visual Studio but I think these are more about formatting than directly related the ReferenceError on the JS since the JS is loaded as I can link to the function from the page source.

Any pointers as to what to look at or how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This had me stumped for a moment.

All the Javascript was there (linkable from bundle links in the page source), all the files were there, everything worked in dev (doesn’t it always?).

Anyway, if you’re seeing this error in your deployed applications there are a couple of steps to take.

Firstly you should download and install the Visual Studio tool [JSLint.VS2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1a417c37-4d6f-43ca-b753-6ea6eb5041fd). Then set this up to show warnings and don’t set it up to fail the build. JSLint is not kind and very strict about things (your adherence to BP is your choice but recommended for sure!)

So, you deploy your app and BANG all your lovely JS is broken. Never fear … pop over to your web app Global.asax file and in the Application_Start method include this:

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

So now with this setting set you can launch your app in debug mode within Visual Studio with all the optimizations forced on to test minification and more closely model your testing to the deployed version.

Once you have that working and are seeing the problems more clearly you can start to work through the potential issues using the reports from your new JSLint VS plugin to fix the syntax and other formatting issues.